# UIPickerView not showing images in iOS 7 + versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewdelegate

I'm trying to run my app in iOS 7+ versions wherein struck with one issue

I have UIPickerview showing images correctly for versions lessthan iOS 7 but in iOS 7+ entire picker view is messed up. Here's what im trying to achieve

1. I have array of imageViews in Viewload
2. Trying to display same in ViewForRow method. Please check code below

   ```
   //In ViewDidLoad()
    NSArray *box12names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Black",@"Brown",@"Red",@"Orange",@"Yellow",@"Green",nil];

   self.box1_views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10]; 

   // From code below , Box1_Black, Box1_Brown etc... are my png images in APP

   for (NSString *str in box12names) {
   NSString *filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Box1_%@.png",str];
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
   UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

   [self.box1_views addObject:imageview];
   [filename release];
   [imageview release];

   }

    [self.box1_views release];

   self.box2_views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10]; 

   for (NSString *str in box12names) {
   NSString *filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Box2_%@.png",str];
   UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];

   [self.box2_views addObject:imageview];
   [filename release];
   [imageview release];

   }

   [self.box2_views release];

   [box12names release];


   //In PickerViewDelegate method

   -(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view

   {

   NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"box%d_views", component +1];

   NSArray *array = [self valueForKey:arrayName];

   UIView *tempview = [array objectAtIndex:row];

   [arrayName release];

   return tempview;

   }



   //Here my picker view is displaying wierdly with iOS 7+ version whereas works good with iOS 6
   ```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved -

```
{
NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"band%d_views", component +1];
NSArray *array = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
//UIView *tempview = [array objectAtIndex:row];
UIView *tempview=[[UIView alloc] init];
[tempview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[[array objectAtIndex:row] image]]];

[arrayName release];
return tempview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt add subview of imageview in the pickerview's reusing view.So try this below line in **pickerView:viewForRow** method:

```
tempView.addSubview(imageView);
```

Comment: Put the imageView from the viewDidiLoad to ViewforRow,

Comment: Keep in mind, if you need imageView in more than 1 method then declare the imageview @interfave in .m file

Comment: code in view did load: ` NSArray *arrImage = @[@"box1.png", @"box2.png", @"box3.png", @"box4.png", @"box5.png"]; // contains name of images`
code in delegate: ` UIView *tempView = [UIView new];// give frame if needed
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:arrImage[row]]];
    [tempView addSubview:imgView];
    
    return tempView;`

Comment: Try this above it may help, and sorry if comment it totally get messed up.

Comment: Thanks Tinu. I actually tried adding Image using UIColor colorwithPatternIMage and it worked like I expected